# How do I set a php variable as one of the columns in my workbench database? Example: $ student = cd_student

Tags: php, mysql, html, variables, mysql-workbench

I want to make a simple database system for my school (activity) and I need to get, for example, the name that the guy put in the first text box, take this information, say the name of student = nm_student, Store that data, and display all the information that he typed on the screen. I was able to get these items but I could not store these data in the contents of my MySQL column, so if someone can help me, I would appreciate it

What I need:

```
$name = nm_student

$birth = dt_birth_student

$rm = cd_rm_student
```

---

[image]

---

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<html>
<body>

<?php
include("connect.php");
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
  name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <br>
  RM:<br>
  <input type="text" name="RM" value="">
  <br><br>
  Data of birth: <br>
  <input type="date" name="birth" value="">
  <br><br>
  <a href=""><input type="submit"  name="register" value="register"></a>
</form> 
<br>
<?php
include("select.php");    
?>    
</body>
</html>
```

PHP: CONNECT CODE

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","student");

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("connection fail" . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

PHP: SELECT CODE

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM student";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


if(isset($_POST["register"])){
    $name = $_POST ["name"];
    $rm = $_POST ["rm"];
    $birth = $_POST ["birth"];
}

?>
```

MY SQL WORKBENCH CODE:

```
create table student(
cd_rm_student int,
nm_student varchar(100),
dt_birth_student date,
CONSTRAINT PK_alunos PRIMARY KEY (cd_rm_student)
);
```

Comment: fetch: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php